# onmouseover wont work with my function?

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover

I am currently learning to use java script, and have come across a problem I cant solve. 
in a simple HTM for the sake of practice I have made an script that modifies the top margin of  a div:

```
var boton = (function () {
var timerId;

return function (margin, element) {
    var i = 2;
    timerId = setInterval (function () {
    if (i > margin) 
        i = 2;
        element.style.marginTop = i + 'px';
        i++;
    }, 100);
}; }) ();
```

If I call the function this way it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
boton (50 , document.getElementById("botondiv"));
</script>
```

But if I try to call it within a mouseover event on an A tag it wont work

```
<a onmouseover="boton (50 , document.getElementById("botondiv"));" href="#"></a>
```

My idea on this is that when some one hovers over the A tag the top margin of the element is modified. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have quotes inside quotes with no escaping, for one.

```
<a onmouseover="boton (50 , document.getElementById("botondiv"));" href="#"></a>
```

Should be:

```
<a onmouseover="boton (50 , document.getElementById('botondiv'));" href="#"></a>
```